# recovery.conf not getting changed to recovery.done after PITR

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-10, pitr

In `recovery.conf`, if we give `recovery_target_time` as 2018-09-07 03:25:46 (without EST) and restart PostgreSQL, `recovery.conf` is not getting changed to `recovery.done`.

Yet PITR is successful and records/tables are restored only till given time. But then the database remains in recovery mode and I am unable to modify data.

In the second case, if I add EST and restart PostgreSQL, `recovery.conf` is getting changed to `recovery.done`, but everything is getting restored. I mean tables/records added after 2018-09-07 03:25:46 are also restored.

Other information: doing it on a Linux host. `Timezone` in `postgresql.conf` is `US/Eastern`

`postgresql.conf` has the following settings configured. Other options are commented out.

```
listen_addresses = '*'
port = 5432
max_connections = 100
shared_buffers = 128MB
dynamic_shared_memory_type = posix
wal_level = replica
archive_mode = on
archive_command = 'cp %p /archive/%f'
log_destination = 'stderr'
logging_collector =on
log_timezone = 'US/Eastern'
datestyle = 'iso, mdy'
timezone ='US/Eastern'
lc_messages = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_monetary ='en_US.UTF-8'
lc_numeric = 'en_US.UTF-8'
lc_time = 'en_US.UTF-8'
default_text_search_config = 'pg_catalog.english'
```

`recovery.conf' has the following two options enabled:

```
restore_command = 'cp /archive/%f %p'
recovery_target_time = '2018-09-07 03:25:46'


2018-09-07 03:35:57.745 EDT [8264] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2018-09-07 03:23:31 EDT
2018-09-07 03:35:59.593 EDT [8264] LOG:  starting point-in-time recovery to 2018-09-07 03:25:46-04
2018-09-07 03:35:59.682 EDT [8264] LOG:  restored log file "000000010000000000000003" from archive
2018-09-07 03:35:59.722 EDT [8264] LOG:  redo starts at 0/3000028
2018-09-07 03:35:59.725 EDT [8264] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 0/3000130
2018-09-07 03:35:59.725 EDT [8262] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2018-09-07 03:36:00.058 EDT [8264] LOG:  restored log file "000000010000000000000004" from archive
2018-09-07 03:36:00.097 EDT [8264] LOG:  recovery stopping before commit of transaction 562, time 2018-09-07 03:26:17.435255-04
2018-09-07 03:36:00.097 EDT [8264] LOG:  recovery has paused
2018-09-07 03:36:00.097 EDT [8264] HINT:  Execute pg_wal_replay_resume() to continue.
2018-09-07 03:36:54.138 EDT [8288] ERROR:  cannot execute CREATE TABLE in a read-only transaction
2018-09-07 03:36:54.138 EDT [8288] STATEMENT:  CREATE TABLE scale_data5 ( section NUMERIC NOT NULL, id1 NUMERIC NOT NULL, id2 NUMERIC NOT NULL );
```

Answer (score 4):

As you can see, recovery pauses after reaching the target.

This is because you have `hot_standby = on` and you left [`recovery_target_action`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/recovery-target-settings.html#RECOVERY-TARGET-ACTION) at its default value `pause`.

You have to add the following in `recovery.conf`:

```
recovery_target_action = promote
```

Alternatively, you can connect to the recovering server and complete recovery manually:

```
SELECT pg_wal_replay_resume();
```

To solve the mystery why adding the time zone makes a difference, compare the time zone in the log (EDT) to the time zone you used (EST).

Your database is running in ***Eastern Daylight Time***, which is offset -4 hours from UTC, while ***Eastern Standard Time*** is offset -5 hours.

So what happened is that by using “EST” you actually specified a recovery target time corresponding to `2018-09-07 04:25:46 EDT`, which was past the end of WAL, so PostgreSQL did a complete recovery.

Comment: This is great. It worked for me now. Thanks a lot for your help.